# How to print the steps of linear system solver in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am working on linear system solver with tkinter.
It takes the number of variables and makes an augmented matrix then print the solution and also the steps. But I have a problem with the labels I added to for loop. It should print the steps but not working.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, StringVar, Button, Entry, IntVar
from fractions import Fraction
from array import array
import numpy as np
from math import *
from fractions import Fraction
import termcolor


# Define Programe
window = Tk()
window.title("Linear System Solver")
window.geometry("640x500+120+120")
# window.configure(bg='Black')

# Function To get matrix From entry Box
Label(
    window,
    text="Enter The Number Of Variables :",
    font=("arial", 10, "bold"),
    bg="Yellow",
).place(x=20, y=5)

ent = Entry(window, textvariable=IntVar())
ent.place(x=235, y=7)
# ent.pack()

vars = int(ent.get())


text_var = []
entries = []
x = np.zeros(vars)

#x = np.zeros(vars)


Label(window, text="Enter The Augmented Matrix :", font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(
    x=20, y=80
)



  


# Check if matrix[i][i]==0 ==> if That Sawp


      

def Make_gui():
    x2 = 0
    y2 = 0
    vars = int(ent.get())
    for i in range(vars):
        # append an empty list to your two arrays
        # so you can append to those later
        text_var.append([])
        entries.append([])
        for j in range(vars + 1):
            # append your StringVar and Entry
            text_var[i].append(IntVar())
            entries[i].append(Entry(window, textvariable=text_var[i][j], width=3))
            entries[i][j].place(x=240 + x2, y=100 + y2)
            x2 += 30


        y2 += 30
        x2 = 0
    global matrix
    matrix = []
    for i in range(vars):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range( vars + 1):
            matrix[i].append(text_var[i][j].get())
    
            
            
    return matrix


def Result():
    mat = np.array(Make_gui())
    Label(window,text=(mat), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=200, y=300)   
    
 
    for i in range(vars):
        if mat[i][i] == 0 and i < (vars - 1):
            for j in range(vars + 1):
                temp = mat[i][j]
                mat[i][j] = mat[i + 1][j]
                mat[i + 1][j] = temp
                
                Label(window,text=(temp), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=200, y=300) 
                
                #Label(window, text=(f'I Swap Row{i} with Row {i+1} and thisis new matrix:\n'), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=100, y=100)
                #Label(window, text=(mat), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=20, y=300)
                
        Label(window, text=(f'I Swap Row{i} with Row {i+1} and thisis new matrix:\n'), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=200, y=400)
    
    

                    
        for i in range(vars):
            for j in range(vars):
                if i != j:
                    inverse = mat[j][i] / mat[i][i]
                    for k in range(vars + 1):
                        mat[j][k] = Fraction(mat[j][k] - inverse * mat[i][k])
                        Label(window, text=(mat[j][k]), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=44, y=356)

                    Label(window, text=(mat), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=50, y=300)

        for i in range(vars):
            x[i] = Fraction(mat[i][vars] / mat[i][i])
            Label(window, text=(x[i]), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=60, y=70)
           # Label.config(window, text=(mat[i][j]), font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bg="Yellow").place(x=200, y=100)

  
  

button = Button(window, text="Submit", bg="Yellow", width=15, command=Make_gui)
button.place(x=240, y=40)

button = Button(window, text="Result", bg="Yellow", width=15, command=Result)
button.place(x=240, y=250)

window.mainloop()
```

I tried to add labels in for loop. I expect to print steps in the window.

Comment: Did you get some kind of error? You create labels in a loop, but place them all in one place. In this case, you will only see the label with the last text. Do you want to print the steps as a list, or something like change the text in one place in the window (like a timer)?

Comment: I want to print each step and the matrix after that step.

Comment: Print steps in what form? Like a column, top to bottom? To see all the steps, from the first to the last?

Comment: Yes, I want to see all the steps, from the first to last.

Comment: The name [vars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is reserved for a built-in function, you'd better not use it for variables.

Comment: Your function `def Result` doesn't actually do anything: `for i in range(0)`. This is because you are taking the value of the user input at the very beginning of the script. Even before the user had time to enter something. `vars = int(ent.get())` -> default `0` from entry. If you move those two lines into a function: `vars = int(ent.get())` and `x = np.zeros(vars)`, it will do the calculations. But, again, if you place all the labels on the same coordinates, then you will see only the last one.